# Android db.delete(); on ListActivity

Tags: java, android, sql

I need help on a matter...

I created a listview with a cursord adapter that connects to my database,and shows me a list of everything that I saved in my table.
I later created a context menu that appears with longckick on the desired line

context position

```
         id = getListAdapter().getItemId(info.position);
```

this is my method delete in the databaseHelper

```
void deleteReg(SQLiteDatabase db)
    {

        db.delete(TabellaRegistry.TABLE_NAME,null, null);
    }
```

and i use that in my activity for delete the selected line:

```
   final SQLiteDatabase db = databaseHelper.getWritableDatabase();
                                databaseHelper.deleteReg(db,null, null, null, null, null, null);
```

but doing so...i delete all in my table...

how do I delete only the selected line via the context menu?

I hope I explained myself, thanks in advance

Comment: Read doc for db.delete again!!! Passing nulls as 2nd and 3rd params WILL delete whole data from table

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By passing NULL as your second argument on this line:

```
db.delete(TabellaRegistry.TABLE_NAME,null, null);
```

You will always be deleting the whole table. As mentioned in the Android documentation, the parameters are as following:

> **public int delete (String table, String whereClause, String[] whereArgs)**
>
> table     - the table to delete from
>
> whereClause  - the optional WHERE clause to apply when deleting.
>   Passing null will delete all rows.

So let's say you want to delete the line where BOOK_ID is 6 you would have something like:

```
public boolean deleteTitle(String id) 
{
    return db.delete(DATABASE_TABLE, BOOK_ID + "=" + id, null) > 0;
}
```

SQLite Class Overview: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html

Comment: I knew that passing null on whereClause will delete all rows,I always write in the example because I managed to do just that.your example was very useful to me thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In order to delete specific rows, you need to put a where clause in the delete statement [delete](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#delete%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D%29)

Answer (score 1):

If  you check the api docs for this method you can get the answer yourself.

```
public int delete (String table, String whereClause, String[] whereArgs)

Parameters

table   the table to delete from
whereClause the optional WHERE clause to apply when deleting. Passing null will delete all rows.
```

You are passing null in where clause which is the cause of deleting all records.