# remove an item from listview

Tags: android, listview, listitem

I need to change the method onListItemClick () to delete the items on the list .. ideas?
I do not know how to adapt it into my class. I have a Db class I and an Helper class.

Here is the code:

```
  Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("select * from " + PRODUCT_TABLE, null);

        setListAdapter(new CursorAdapter(this, cursor, true) {

        @Override
        public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent){

            TextView textView = new TextView(ProdottiSelectionActivity.this);
            return textView;
        }

        @Override
        public void bindView (View view, Context context, Cursor cursor){

            TextView textView = (TextView) view;
            textView.append(cursor.getString(1));
            textView.append("\n");
            textView.append(cursor.getString(2));
            textView.append("\n");
            textView.append(cursor.getString(3));
            textView.append("\n");
            textView.append(cursor.getString(4));
            }
        });
    }

@Override
protected void onDestroy(){
    super.onDestroy();
    dbHelper.close();
    }

@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    setResult(1, new Intent(String.valueOf(id)));
    finish();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need something like following

```
@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    db.open();
    //you have to determine user clicked on which item 
    String[] whereArgs={String.valueOf(item_id)};
    db.delete(DATABASE_TABLE_4,"item_id = ?",whereArgs);    
    cursor.requery();  //deprecated 
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); //deprecated 
    db.close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Run a delete query on the database, that would update the list view as well.

```
db.execSQL("delete from " + PRODUCT_TABLE + " where id = 1", null);
```

for example if you want to delete a product with id = 1, or you could also use the [delete method](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#delete%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D%29).

Also see the questions

- [Android db.delete(); on ListActivity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10198348/android-db-delete-on-listactivity)
- [Android Delete Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6337764/android-delete-query)

which are similar to your question.